# Need "carat" for currently active Superfish menu item

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I have a Drupal 7 Superfish menu (from the Superfish module) that I would like to add a "carat" to for the currently active menu item.

Here is my current menu:
[image]

But I would like a menu where the currently active menu item has a "carat" instead.
Here is what I would like: (altered in photoshop to give carat)
[image]

I'm looking for the easiest way to do this in Drupal 7.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to just use CSS.  You can create that effect using absolutely positioned pseudo elements with some border tricks.  For example:

```
.sf-menu li {
  position: relative;
}

.sf-hover:after, 
.active-trail:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #369;
}
```